# How to apply a VBA function to a selected range and paste results into the same range?

Tags: excel, vba

I have worksheet with integer values and I have written a VBA macro to apply a mathematic operation on the range. I want to apply this macro to all the values in the excel and the results should be pasted in the same cell.

```
Sub KLtoMT()

' convert KL to MT i.e. divide KL by 1.21

    Selection.Value = Val(Selection.Value / 1.21)
    
End Sub
```

this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correct, you want to select range and then using macro apply formula to each cell in selected range. If so, then maybe something like this?

```
Sub TestingTest()

    Dim cell As Object
    
    For Each cell In Selection
        cell.Value = cell.Value / 1.21
    Next cell

End Sub
```

You may also add some checks as well like "If cell is not empty"

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestingTest()

    Dim cell As Object
    
    For Each cell In Selection
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            cell.Value = cell.Value / 1.21
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Or you can perform a check for Selected range. This will display warning message if empty cells are selected, you can edit it to for example if cells are containing a letter or something else.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestingTest()

    Dim cell As Object
    
    For Each cell In Selection
        If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Selection) > 1 Then
            MsgBox "You have selected some empty cells as well!", vbExclamation
            Exit For
        Else
            cell.Value = cell.Value / 1.21
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

For single selected area, [`Evaluate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) can be used :

```
Sub KLtoMT()
    Selection = Evaluate(Selection.Address & " / 1.21")
End Sub
```

For multiple selected areas :

```
Sub KLtoMT()
    For Each area In Selection.Areas
        area.Value = Evaluate(area.Address & " / 1.21")
    Next
End Sub
```